# What is the difference between BLUE and MVUE?

Tags: terminology, unbiased-estimator, efficiency

What is the difference between a Best Linear Unbiased Estimator (BLUE) and a Minimum Variance Unbiased Estimator (MVUE)?

I know that "best" mean efficient, but that is also what "minimum variance" means.

Comment: one is linear, and the other doesn't have to be

Comment: @Taylor I was tempted to ask this question with "MVLUE", but seeing as that acronym isn't used often, I wanted to keep this question more relevant for others. I think there's more to it than that. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minimum-variance_unbiased_estimator) mentions MVUE are the minimum variance "for all possible values of the parameter", which makes me think this term is perhaps used when the estimator depends on an underlying parameter.

Comment: that isn't possible. You estimate parameters with data, not with other unknown parameters

Comment: E.g. FGLS depends on an estimate for the covariance matrix of the errors. Couldn't that covariance matrix be seen as a "parameter", since it is unknown?

Comment: I would like it if the answer to this question could clarify whether the _linear_ property is the _only_ difference, or whether there is indeed another difference. Why would the first word in the acronym be different if it is not important?

Comment: I wonder why BUE isn't a thing...

Comment: You seem to be worried that "best" and "minimum variance" are not the same

Comment: @Aksakal yes. I didn't want to miss out on something important if it was there. My tutor just sent our class an e-mail saying that GLS is MVUE rather than BLUE, but I don't see why she would take the trouble to do that (several hours before our final exam), seeing as we haven't studied non-linear models... and I once asked her in class if it's the same thing, then she said, "Yes."

Comment: tutor's real job is to torture students

Comment: "MVUE" is a little clearer than "BUE" as to what the actual criterion is - "Best" isn't clear at all - to people being exposed to the topic for the first time.   "MVLUE" doesn't have the same catchiness as "BLUE".   Those are my guesses, at any rate.

Answer (score 7):

BLUE means an estimator is Best among the class of Linear and Unbiased Estimators. By best we mean that it is the most efficient estimator in the class of the estimators that are Unbiased plus Linear.
MVUE is the Minimum Variance estimator in the class of Unbiased Estimators. They need not be linear. But yes if any Linear estimator is MVUE then it Certainly is BLUE.

Comment: It is important to note that minimum variance and minimum MSE (mean squared error) are the same thing when you restrict attention to unbiased estimators (bias = 0). In other words, efficiency can be measured by variance.

Comment: +1 for the persistent capitalization according to the little items of the acronym(s).